# add properties to individual and insert them all into my file.owl

Tags: java, jena, owl

I have a class, `MAN`.  I want to add an individual, `jack`, with properties:

```
 hasage="50"
 hasadress="france"
```

How can I create my individual `jack` and add properties to him and save them into my file `database.owl`? Here is the connection.  I use Eclipse and the Jena API.

```java
  JenaOWLModel owlModel ;
  OntModel model;           
  owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI("file:///C:/database.owl");
  model = owlModel.getOntModel();
```

---

i am begging you to help me , it still fiew days for my thesis defence this CODE work perfectly i can save individuals in my file.owl BUT i couldnt add properties to those individuals and save them with.

please help me what should i do , i am realy worried thanks a lot in advance

```
     public class testins { 
static JenaOWLModel owlModel ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
OntModel model;
javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();

try{        
    owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI("file:///D:/file.owl");//  the link of my owl file
    model = owlModel.getOntModel(); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jDialog1,
    "loaded with success","Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);       
   }
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jDialog1,
            "error",
            "Information",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}   


OWLNamedClass theAlert = owlModel.getOWLNamedClass("Alert"); //my class Alert
theAlert.createOWLIndividual("indivname1"); //i add here an indevidual
theAlert.createOWLIndividual("indivname2"); //i add here another indevidual

// now how to add to those two Individuals properties ?? each individual has 2
// properties , the property witch its name est_evaluer and the second est_analyser those 
// to properties will contain values so here is my problem how to add those values to an
// individual and save all of them


       Collection errors ;
       String fileName ;           
       fileName= ("D:/file.owl");
       errors = new ArrayList();

//here i'll save it and it work ,it mean that i find in my file "file.owl" 
//individuals i added witch are "indivname1" and "indivname2" in my class ALERT 
// so now my problem is how to add properties to those indiviuals i add , and save them also

    try{  owlModel.save(new File(fileName).toURI(), FileUtils.langXMLAbbrev, errors);
    System.out.println("File saved with " + errors.size() + " errors.");

  }
  catch(Exception e){         
  }

   }
```

}

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: To elaboate on @fGo's comment, what have you done so far?  What about it hasn't worked?  Jena's OntModel interface provides methods for creating Individuals, and the Individual (and Resource) interface provide methods for adding property assertions.  Do they not suit your needs?

Comment: i realy could'nt find those methods i have a these defence it still 10 days , i realy need a help please , thanx a lot

Comment: @FreedomOfSpeech They're all in the javadocs for Jena;  [`OntModel`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) and [`Individual`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/Individual.html) are good starting points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what the namespace you are using is. So I'm going to assume `http://example.org/example#`, adjust as necessary.

```
String NS = "http://example.org/example#";

// create ex:Man class
OntClass man = model.createClass( NS + "Man" );

// create individual ex:jack
Individual jack = model.createIndividual( NS + "jack", man );

// create some properties - probably better to use FOAF here really
DatatypeProperty age = model.createDatatypeProperty( NS + "age" );
DatatypeProperty address = model.createDatatypeProperty( NS + "address" );

jack.addProperty( age, model.createTypedLiteral( 50 ) )
    .addProperty( address, model.createLiteral( "France" ) );
```

Comment: thanx a lot but how to save my ontmodel ? the new one witch i add to it individuals+properties .

Comment: See the documentation: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#write(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)